# How to use index(of:) with [SomeProtocol]?

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I've got a bunch of classes that are UIViews. Some conform to a particular protocol. I've got an array of these particular ones, but I can't call index(of:) on this array (this code can be pasted into a Playground):

```
import UIKit

protocol ViewWithColor {}

class BlackView: UIView {}
class WhiteView: UIView {}
class BlueView: UIView, ViewWithColor {}
class GreenView: UIView, ViewWithColor {}
class YellowView: UIView, ViewWithColor {}

let blackView = BlackView()
let whiteView = WhiteView()
let blueView = BlueView()
let greenView = GreenView()
let yellowView = YellowView()

let allViews = [blackView, whiteView, blueView, greenView, yellowView]
let viewsWithColorArray: [ViewWithColor] = [blueView, greenView, yellowView]

let index1 = allViews.index(of: blueView)
let index2 = viewsWithColorArray.index(of: blueView)
```

The error is:

```
cannot invoke 'index' with an argument list of type '(of: BlueView)'
```

The function cannot be called because the protocol ViewWithColor doesn't conform to `Equatable`. Do I really have to implement equatable? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @vadian said, you can use the version of `index` that takes a closure.  In this case, you are looking for a specific instance, so use `index(where: { $0 === blueView })`.

The `===` operator:

> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether two references point to the
>   same object instance.

Also, you need to make your protocol `ViewWithColor` a `class` protocol because `===` only works with class instances.

```
protocol ViewWithColor: class {}

class BlackView: UIView {}
class WhiteView: UIView {}
class BlueView: UIView, ViewWithColor {}
class GreenView: UIView, ViewWithColor {}
class YellowView: UIView, ViewWithColor {}

let blackView = BlackView()
let whiteView = WhiteView()
let blueView = BlueView()
let greenView = GreenView()
let yellowView = YellowView()

let allViews = [blackView, whiteView, blueView, greenView, yellowView]
let viewsWithColorArray: [ViewWithColor] = [blueView, greenView, yellowView]

let index1 = allViews.index(where: { $0 === blueView })
print(index1 ?? -1)
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

```
let index2 = viewsWithColorArray.index(where: { $0 === blueView })
print(index2 ?? -1)
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the closure syntax and check for the type:

```
let index1 = allViews.index(where: {$0 is BlueView})
let index2 = viewsWithColorArray.index(where: {$0 is BlueView})
```

Comment: Nice idea, but that won't work in my case. For index2, I'm not looking for all views of type BlueView, but for one specific instance. There could be multiple BlueView instances in the viewsWithColorArray

Comment: Regardless of the syntax `index(of` or `index(where` on success you'll get always the index of the **first** occurrence which matches the condition.

Comment: How about `index(where: { $0 === blueView })` to find the specific instance?

Comment: @vacawama error: 'BlueView' is not implicitly convertible to 'AnyHashable'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert?